# Remove event handlers of children but not self with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, unbind

I have a div that has a child span which in turn has an another child span.
I hook the parent div with mouseDown event like this:

```
$("." + cellClass).mousedown(mouseDownEvent);
```

But this also hooks the children with the event. How can I unbind the children or just bind the div?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("." + cellClass).children().unbind();
```

This doesn't work:

```
function mouseDownEvent(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    isMouseDown = !isMouseDown;
    var cell = event.target;
    selectedCells = []; // reset
    selectedCells = addCellToSelection(cell, selectedCells)
}
```

**UPDATE**

The solution proposed by Serlite works to stop the events of the spans. The only problem now is that if the actions take place on the span (even though the mouse is within the DIV) there are no events firing. Which makes sense given that the spans events are off but is there a way to make sure that that the event of the DIV gets fired regardless off whether im on the SPAN or not?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is for the children of your cell to not trigger their parent's callback function (ie. If `mousedown` occurs on a child, don't execute `mouseDownEvent()`), you'll need to stop propagation of the event starting from the child level.

This can be done by binding another callback function to the children of the parent, and calling `stopPropagation()` from there. Using your current naming, this segment of your code could then become:

```
$("." + cellClass).mousedown(mouseDownEvent);
$("." + cellClass).children().mousedown(mouseDownEventChild);
```

Where `mouseDownEventChild()` is simply:

```
function mouseDownEventChild(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLwcqg25/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**

In response to the update to the question, my first thought would be to check whether the child's click event is fired within the bounds of the parent. (There may be a more elegant solution, but this is the most straightforward I could work out.) This would change `mouseDownEventChild()` to:

```
function mouseDownEventChild(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $parentEl = $(this).parent();

    // Traveling up DOM until we find an appropriate parent
    while (!$parentEl.hasClass(cellClass)){
        $parentEl = $parentEl.parent();
    }

    // Checking mouse event is within bounding box
    var parentBounds = $parentEl[0].getBoundingClientRect();    
    if (e.clientX >= parentBounds.left && e.clientX < (parentBounds.left + parentBounds.width) && e.clientY >= parentBounds.top && e.clientY < (parentBounds.top + parentBounds.height)){
        mouseDownEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLwcqg25/4/) to show you the modified behaviour. Let me know if this fits your requirements.

Comment: Great, glad I could help out.

Comment: The only issue now though is that if I click on the cell in he part where the span is the event doesn't fire even through the mouse is within the div. is it possible to to get round this ?

Comment: @ArmenSafieh-Garabedian Hi, please let me know if the previous edit to my answer was sufficient to address your question, or if you require additional assistance.